# How to import css file from node_modules in Vue-component

Tags: css, webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to connect this [toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr)-library into my component:

#### my-component.vue

```
<script>
  import toastr from 'toastr';

  export default {
    mounted(){
      toastr.success('Hello from toastr!');
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    Template for my-component.vue here.
  </div>
</template>


<style>
  /* HOW TO IMPORT `toastr.css` FROM NODE_MODULES HERE?
</style>
```

How to connect library's css from node_modules directory?

Comment: @import url("https://unpkg.com/vue-toastr-2/dist/vue-toastr-2.min.css")

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [@LinusBorg](https://github.com/LinusBorg) suggested [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader/issues/144#issuecomment-251955623) in vue-loader discussion thread, you can use `src`-attribute inside `<style>`-tag:

#### my-component.vue

```
<script>
  import toastr from 'toastr';

  export default {
    mounted(){
      toastr.success('Hello from toastr!');
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    Template for my-component.vue here.
  </div>
</template>


<style src='toastr/build/toastr.min.css'></style>
```

Comment: yup its work: <style src='../../node_modules/@toast-ui/editor/dist/toastui-editor.css'></style> <style scoped></style>

Comment: Should also work without node_modules simply with toast-ui/editor/dist/toastui-editor.css.